# specifying the right perl version for git

Tags: git, perl, hp-ux

We want to install git on our system which runs HP UX 11.31 and the standard version of Perl (5.8.8e) which comes with the system. It is of utmost importance that the perl command keeps referring to Perl 5.8.8e so that our scripts run fine.

Git has a dependency on Perl 5.28. Mind, it was working fine with Perl 5.8.8e but we'd rather not risk running into issues later, so we installed it in a separate folder.

Now how can we make sure that git uses the correct version of Perl?

Comment: Re "*Git has a dependency on Perl 5.28*", That's not true. The docs doesn't even mention it requires Perl (though it does mention it requires some Perl modules), so I suspect it only requires Perl 5.8.

Comment: http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Development/Tools/git-2.20.1/ on this website it states perl as a dependency. But yes it doesn't necessarily mean it has to be 5.28. Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Have you considered moving away from a version of Perl that is over twelve years old? What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: rrreaaaaallly strict system administrators and lots of legacy code. And expensive devs. And a general culture of "if it ain't broken don't fix it." which is fair enough. It should be possible to run them side-by-side.

Comment: @bluppfisk, No, that doesn't say git depends on 5.28. It says that package requires the perl 5.28 package. It says that because the git package was created on a system with perl 5.28, not because git requires 5.28 (which came out earlier this year and which I've never installed, even though I've been using git for many many years)

Comment: okay good! I noticed the only reason there's a perl "dependency" seems to be that there's a perl API included in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perl scripts that Git runs begin with `#!` lines.  In the Git source, these lines read `#!/usr/bin/perl`, but as you build Git to install it, the source-builder *replaces* these with the correct path.  So if the correct path for a correct version of Perl is `/usr/local/bin/perl`, tell the build to use that; if it's `/compat/perl5.28`, tell the build to use that, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), the minimum version requirement for Perl to 5.8.1 (from September 2002).

That is because newer versions of `Getopt::Long` started giving warnings against our (ab)use of it in `git send-email`.
Bump the Perl version to simplify our implementation.

See [commit 6ff658c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ff658cc78f36baa74c0f25314b0043a8f4b4fc6), [commit d13a73e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d13a73e383076636534e10ba799af0c9a2b85357) (16 Nov 2023) by [Todd Zullinger (`tmzullinger`)](https://github.com/tmzullinger).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1ef1cce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ef1cce9c254d3787586ac87c1d1a2ca2c00bfd3), 09 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`perl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d13a73e383076636534e10ba799af0c9a2b85357): bump the required Perl version to 5.8.1 from 5.8.0
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Todd Zullinger</sup>

> The following commit will make use of a Getopt::Long feature which is only present in Perl >= 5.8.1.
> Document that as the minimum version we support.
>
> Many of our Perl scripts will continue to run with 5.8.0 but this change allows us to adjust them as needed without breaking any promises to our users.
>
> The Perl requirement was last changed in [d48b284](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d48b28418355ef41a9501eb28a82ec0b69e62a17) ("`perl`: bump the required Perl version to 5.8 from 5.6.[21]", 2010-09-24, Git v1.7.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b73ce74e6abfb45626bce7a21465e6db6302be0)).
> At that time, 5.8.0 was 8 years old.
> It is now over 21 years old.

`CodingGuidelines` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d13a73e383076636534e10ba799af0c9a2b85357/Documentation/CodingGuidelines#L493):

> - We try to support Perl 5.8.1 and later ("use Perl 5.008001").